# Predict with Logistic Regression Error - unexpected '=' in data.frame

Tags: regression, predict

I received the following error while trying to predict with logistic regression in R.

> Error: unexpected '=' in "New_temp =data.frame(motor_data$Winding_temp_U ="

I am trying to predict `motor_data$Week_1_break` (Y variable) when `motor_data$Winding_temp_U` (X variable) = 130, 150 and 180.

Here is my code.

```
motor_data <-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
attach (motor_data)
motor_data$Winding_temp_U = as.numeric(motor_data$winding_temp_U)
motor_data$Week_1_break = as.factor (motor_data$week_1_break)
logit_1<-glm(motor_data$Week_1_break~motor_data$Winding_temp_U, binomial())
New_temp =data.frame(motor_data$Winding_temp_U = c(130, 150, 180))
predict(logit_1, New_temp, type = "response")
curve(predict(logit_1, data.frame(motor_data$Winding_temp_U=x),type="resp")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a new data.frame with values 130, 150 and 180? Do

```
New_temp = data.frame("Winding_temp_U" = c(130, 150, 180))
```

instead of

```
New_temp =data.frame(motor_data$Winding_temp_U = c(130, 150, 180))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to assign values 130, 150, 180 to the X variable (`motor_data$Winding_temp_U`) in the context of predict Y variable. Creating a new variable (`Winding_temp_U`) wouldn't help, would it?

Comment: Did you want to predict y with the new X values 130, 150, 180?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do - predict y with the new X value of 130, 150, 180.

Comment: Yes, you can create a new variable and predict with the new data frame. Just do as the answer says and that should work.